# Update string to ObjectId of children in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, find, updates

I have a collection named "users" that has an array inside named "companies". That means that each "user" can have one or more "companies". One document looks like this.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b0b5aed0902a519d0440b37"),
"email" : "mario@example.com",
"name" : "Mario",
"last_name" : "Perez",
"companies" : [ 
    {
        "id" : "5b0b456bf7a87830b4d20058",
        "name" : "COMPANY A"
    }, 
    {
        "id" : "5b0b755b576ac70014ad441c",
            "name" : "COMPANY B"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to convert all the companies.id (string) to ObjectId.

So I made this update but it's not really working. I think there is a problem with the way I try to convert the string (companies.id) to ObjectId.

```
db.getCollection('users').update({ "_id": ObjectId("5b0b5aed0902a519d0440b37") }, {$set: {"companies.$[].id": ObjectId("companies.$[].id")}}, {multi: true})
```

I would appreciate it if you can help me.

Comment: Which version of mongodb you are using?

Comment: Im using Mongo 3.4

Comment: Your above code will not work because you cannot access same field in update. If you can update to 4.0 then you can use some aggregation to achieve the result.

Comment: And what if i use a For each?

Comment: yes can be done with some looping

Comment: Ive done this, but still not getting it:

`db.getCollection('users').find({ "_id": ObjectId("5b0b5aed0902a519d0440b37") }).forEach( function(i) {
    db.getCollection('users').update(
      { _id: i._id },
      { $set: { "companies.$.id": new ObjectId(i.companies.$.id) } }
    )
   });`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after trying different ways, I got the answer!

```
db.getCollection('users').find({ "_id": ObjectId("5b0b5aed0902a519d0440b37") }).forEach(function (x) {
x.companies.forEach(function (y) {
    var id_object = new ObjectId(y.id);
    db.getCollection('users').update(x,{$set: {"companies.$[].id": id_object}});
});
```

});